# How do I echo SQL data from database table into a <select> form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wonder if anyone can help.

I am trying to echo some SQL data into a `<select>` form with each `<option>` as a different row from the table.

For example if my table has two columns 'username' and 'category' and there are two rows for the same username, with the data:

"username: test, category: test1."

& second row as:

"username: test, category: test2."

How could I echo 'test1' and 'test2' as two options in a select form?

The table name is 'testtable' so my current `$sql` query is `("SELECT 'category' FROM 'testtable' WHERE 'username = \'$user\'")`

`$user` is currently set to the `$_SESSION['username']`

Code examples would be really helpful and much appreciated. I just cant seem to get them to echo in examples I have found on forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<select name="your_select_name" id="your_select_id">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT `category` FROM `testtable` WHERE `username` = '$username' ") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['category'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

For distinct category use this

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(`category`) as category FROM `testtable` WHERE `username` = '$username' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

OR

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `category` FROM `testtable` WHERE `username` = '$username' GROUP BY category ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Hi Satish, thank you for commenting. I am just going to give this a try now. Will keep you posted. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Satish I gave it a try but like the other code below from Roland, it is coming back with blank dropdown options? Do you have any idea why this would be. I have double-checked my database connection and all seems fine and I am getting no `mysql_error()`'s on the page? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: check your session variable is set or not and what value is in it

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS! I was calling another script which had $username set already! So I just set it back to $user.... Thank you very much! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Just another quick question sorry... If I am posting this option in a form and the next time I re-do the form I will have a duplicate option. Do you know how I could stop the option from duplicating?

Comment: For example if I post 'test2' I will have options next time of 'test1','test2' & 'test2' again?

Comment: use `GROUP BY category` or `SELECT DISTINCT(category)`

Answer (score 1):

You got from your query all rows:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT category FROM testtable WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] ."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$options = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $options[] = "<option>" . $row['category'] . "</option>";
}
?>

<select>
    <?php echo implode("",$options); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Roland, Thank you for your response. I have tried your code however the options dropdown is coming up blank. Do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: Missing closing bracket after while statement

Answer (score 0):

Your select query has an error: unpaired single quote before username, and single quotes surrounding category - is that possible that was the reason you couldn't do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select>
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
   {?>
   <option><?php echo $row['category'];?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<select>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo  "<option>".$row['category']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```